# Flutter Getx argument is never reset

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am working with flutter and trying to use Getx package for passing arguments between components and my problem is that the arguments are never put to null after use. As the component i am navigating to's view depend on these argument i read, i don't have the right after one argument passing. To explain :  navigate this way

```
 Get.offAll(() => Home(), arguments: 1);   <==== arguments represents an initial tab Index in Home
```

then in Home

```
 DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: Get.arguments?? 0, <=== Get.arguments is never null again after line executed once
      length: tabs.length,
```

Generally arguments are no more null in any other Widget even if i navigate to without passing arguments

I know i could directly use the constructor to pass the value but i simplified the case.

So what am i missing? I searched a lot and logically in my head i don't understand how to reset the arguments

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `Get.arguments` is a `getter` not a `setter`, you cannot change it's value like this:

```
Get.arguments = null; // you can't do this
```

however, I see that you're trying to use the `Get.arguments` only once and then, you want it to behave like it's `null`, right?

So instead of using `Get.arguments` directly, store it in another variable, then use that variable in the `initialIndex` property like the following.

inside the class add this `static` count variable:

```
static int useCount = 0;
```

we will track how many times we tried to use `Get.arguments`.

```
  dynamic argumnetsMangedByUseCount() {
      if (useCount >= 1) {
        return null;
      }
      useCount++;
    
      return Get.arguments;
    }
```

instead of `Get.arguments`, we will use this method so it returns either `null` or `Get.arguments` based on `useCount`.

the `1` number represents the max allowed times that it should return `Get.arguments`, otherwise it will return `null`.

Finally, in your `DefaultTabController` :

```
DefaultTabController(
  initialIndex: argumnetsMangedByUseCount() ?? 0,
  length: tabs.length,
```

now after you have a hot restart for the app, you will get the `Get.arguments` only once, after that you will get `null` on it.

Comment: thank you for your fast answer. i hope it would be another way to deal with that problem. understood the logic. finally used a singleton to store temporary values . thanks again !